# masterCheckbox in a datatable

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, datatable, webix

I'm trying to add a masterCheckbox to the webix datatable items. For now, I got the following behavior: when I click on the master checkbox, the values rewrite to 1 or 0

```
{ 
    id:"title", 
    checkValue:"on", 
    uncheckValue:"off", 
    template:"{common.checkbox()} #title#", 
    header:["Title", {content:"masterCheckbox", contentId:"checkAll"}],
    fillspace:true
}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/26750201

Aby idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only example with the masterCheckbox I found is [this sample](http://docs.webix.com/samples/15_datatable/04_editing/16_master_checkbox.html).

Seems like the masterCheckbox changes the ***value*** in the current column. I.e. in your sample `title` becomes `on` or `off`. I suppose the provided use-case is to have a separate column with `{common.checkbox()}`:

```
columns:[
  { id:"ch1", header:{ content:"masterCheckbox", contentId:"mc1" }, template:"{common.checkbox()}", width:40}      
],
```

Sample: http://webix.com/snippet/17a28a40