# Disable datatable checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, datatable, webix

Regarding my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878786/mastercheckbox-in-a-datatable) I have another issue: is there any way to disable the datatable checkboxes in Webix?

For now, I found the `blockEvent()` API, but it allows me only revert the values within the onCheck event. It totally crushes the work of the masterCheckbox:

```
on:{
  onCheck:function(rowId, colId, value){        
    if(colId == "ch1")
      this.blockEvent(); 
    var item = this.getItem(rowId);
    item.ch1 = item.ch1?0:1; 
    this.updateItem(rowId, item);       
    this.unblockEvent();            
  }
}
```

Here's the [**snippet**](http://webix.com/snippet/0d4a6117) that demonstrates the issue.

Is there another approach? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use disable/enable functions instead of blockEvent/unblockEvent respectively.

**[update]**
As per understanding of your question, I have implemented custom type for the checkbox which will disable all the checkboxes inititally except the masterCheckbox. If you click on the masterCheckbox then it works fine, else if you try to edit a particular checkbox then they rest disabled. Please see the code below for **"type"**:

```
type:{
          checkbox:function(obj, common, value, config){
            var checked = (value == config.checkValue) ? 'checked="true"' : '';
            return "<input class='webix_table_checkbox' type='checkbox' "+checked+""+(obj.id>0?"disabled":"")+">";
          }
     }
```

You can check the snippet here: http://webix.com/snippet/9d99ed02

Comment: but in such case values are still reversed when the master checkbox is clicked, just as it was before :(